# How to build for iPhone 2 (iOS 3.xxx) in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios-simulator

I want to build app for iPhone 2 (iOS version upto 3.xxx) in XCode 4, please help me.
(how to add simulator...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think that you should download a previous sdk version (so an xcode too) ..so you should search for a compatible sdk version with iphone2 .This link may help you http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html (install this sdk in a folder different from the developer one to mantain the current one)